# Is there any Oracle processes that exists only when database is in open mode?

Tags: oracle

I need to monitor whether the Oracle database is in open mode through Linux. Are there any processes that mandatorily exist only when the database is open? (not exists when mounted, or restricted, or started).

Comment: Why is it important to differentiate? For practical purposes, if it isn't open, it's down for all but DBAs even if it's in a mounted or restricted state. Logically, if there are no processes it is *down*; if there are processes but it isn't open/accepting connections and produces ORA-01033 during login then it is in some kind of transitory or restricted state; if you're able to login then it is open.

Answer (score 0):

The instance's set of processes all start on instance start (before mount and open). There may be something non-critical that starts after open, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Assuming you have a crontab firing a shell script under the oracle software owner (with your environment properly set up), you can use sqlplus to connect locally: `sqlplus / as sysdba` which will connect if the instance is started, even if it is not yet mounted or if it is mounted by not yet open. You can then obtain the state of the database by querying `v$instance`:

```
SELECT status,
       logins
  FROM v$instance
```

Check for `status LIKE '%OPEN%'` to determine if it's open or not. You can also check if `logins = 'RESTRICTED'` to see if it's open in restricted mode. You can also check `archiver`, `shutdown_pending` and `database_status` for additional conditions that can prevent logins and normal application activity.

Of course, to check if the instance isn't even started, you simply look for its background processes. Typically `pmon` is used to indicate an instance running or not (`ps -ef | grep ora_pmon_$SID` where $SID is your instance name).